# dask distributed: How to increase timeout for worker connections? connect() didn't finish in time

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

`OSError: Timed out trying to connect to 'tcp://127.0.0.1:40475' after 10 s: Timed out trying to connect to 'tcp:// 8.56.11:40475' after 10 s: connect() didn't finish in time`

Having some huge operations running, I would like to increase the timeout using the [Convertion Tool](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/configuration.html#conversion-utility). But I wonder, which configuration option is really used here?

I tried:

```
os.environ["DASK_DISTRIBUTED__COMM__TIMEOUTS__CONNECT"] = "33s"
os.environ["DASK_DISTRIBUTED__COMM__TIMEOUTS__TCP"] = "35s"
os.environ["DASK_DISTRIBUTED__DEPLOY__LOST_WORKER"] = "34s"
```

but no effect (still 10 seconds for the timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in `~/.dask/config.yaml`:

```
# Communication options
connect-timeout: 10      # seconds delay before connecting fails
tcp-timeout: 30         # seconds delay before calling an unresponsive connection dead
default-scheme: tcp
```

Answer (score 2):

From the dask docs: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/configuration.html

The accepted answer is now out of date- while supported use of `~/.dask/config.yml` is deprecated.